# it seems like the whole page is refreshing even thought i am using Ajax.Beginform

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have the following code that i am trying to change from a regular page to an ajax page so when i submit the form, i only refresh the LInkList div.  I change the using line to use Ajax.BeginForm

Here is the View Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div id="LinkList">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("TestUserControl", Model); %>
</div>
<%using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddNewLink", "Test", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "LinkList" }))
  { %>
<fieldset style="text-align: left">
    <legend>Add New Link</legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Url:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input style="width: 500px" type="text" name="url" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Add Link" name="submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<% } %>
```

Here is the Controller Code:

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult AddNewLink(FormCollection collection_)
    {
        string url = collection_["url"].ToString();

        Test test = new Test();
        test.Name = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("TestUserControl", test);
        }

        return View("Index", test);
    }
```

Any idea why the whole page would refresh in this case instead of just whats inside the div tag?  Request.IsAjaxRequest() always returns false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the whole page refreshing or is the entire page being re-rendered inside your DIV.  If the former, I suspect that you may have a javascript error on the page which will render your AJAX handling in operable and cause it to do a full post.  Check this with IE8 debugging or Firefox/Firebug.  You need to have MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js included on every page where you use the AjaxHelper methods.

If the latter, and I think you will eventually have this problem, it's because you are returning the entire view regardless of whether you get the page via AJAX or a full post.  Add some code to your method to return just the partial view that you are replacing when the request is made via AJAX.

```
 var container = GetContainer(ds1);
 if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
 {
      return PartialView( "LinkList", container );
 }
 else 
 {
      return View( "Index", container );
 }
```

Comment: i put this in and IsAjaxRequest() is returning false.  any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked for javascript errors on the client-side that are causing your javascript submission code to not run.  It will do a full post if your javascript is broken.

Comment: i just created a new testController and test view with no javascript and isajaxrequest still return's false.  i have updated the question

Comment: You have to have the Microsoft Ajax libraries included or it won't be able to do the AJAX request.  Make sure that you MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js included on any page that uses Ajax.BeginForm.

Comment: that was the issue. i didn't have those lines